# Can logging cooperate with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I wanna set a specified name of this run of my python application,such as 'run_1', with argparse.

And log of 'run_1' should to write into a file 'run_1.log'.

Log of 'run_2' should write into another file 'run_2.log' instead of write into the same file.

The purpose is that i wanna run this application in parallel with multiple instances. I want to distinguish log of different runs.

I have tried to set logging in main function. But it seems not work.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = args.name
    # one parameter
    LOGGING_CONFIG={'filename':'xxx/'+name}
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
    module_a=MoudleA() # There is log printed with logging in ModuleA
```

It does not work. There is no log print.

If I set logging in another file 'log.py'

```
LOGGING_CONFIG={'filename':'test'}
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
LOGGER=logging.getlogger(__name__)
```

and in main.py

```
from log import LOGGER
if __name__ == '__main__':
    module_a=MoudleA() # There is log printed with logging in ModuleA
```

There is log printed.

Why is there no log if configurating logging in main function with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some other file/application to keep track of it. One simple solution could be to use a text file and a bash script:

Run this only once on your terminal.

```
echo 0 > runs.txt
```

Use this bash script `run.sh` for running your python app everytime.

`run.sh`:

```
num=$(($(cat runs.txt)+1))
fname=run_$((num)).log
python app.py --logfile fname
echo $num > runs.txt
```

As you can see it will call the python app with an argument of appropriate log file name as argument and then update the number of runs to `runs.txt`

You should have the following in your python script

`app.py`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--logfile", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
LOGGING_CONFIG={'filename':args.logfile}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I mislead the problem. The key is configurate logging. 'run_1' does not matter.

Comment: I mean that the log file name can be specified with parameters. But I can't apply it in logging module.

Comment: The question is updated to make it clear.

Comment: Could you please to have look again? I think the question is more clear now.